# React Native Navigation v2 (wix) Disable TopBar

Tags: android, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I am using the React-Native-Navigation v2 from wix (NOT React-Navigation).
I tried disabling the topBar which is rendered by default.

I used following options and am rendering bottomTabs:

```
Navigation.setDefaultOptions({
  topBar: {
    visible: false,
    _height: 0,
    drawBehind: true,
  },
});
```

The topBar disapears but shows an drawBehind animation on initial opening of the Tabs of bottomTabs.

Is there a way to disable the topBar ?

Best regards

Comment: Thanks for writing the answer back, helped me!

Comment: you should probably answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Didn't knew that this is best practice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added animate: false to the defaultOptions and removed _height

```
Navigation.setDefaultOptions({
  topBar: {
    visible: false,
    drawBehind: true,
    animate: false,
  }
});
```

this worked for me and doesn't show the animating on tabchange